# How do I preserve my save data

Tags: steam, pc, middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I recently got a hankering to play the game again. I've forgotten a fair amount of the game mechanics, and wanted to run through the first bit of the game again. However, my last game is about 66% of the way through, and I don't want to lose that progress. How do I preserve my prior data such that I can get back to it after playing the beginning again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The default location of the saved game state for the Steam edition is in:

  > C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata[user ID]\**241930**\remote\gamedata.sav`

  That is assuming you installed Steam in the default location. The bold part is the ID of the game.
  I haven't tried this myself, but I think you can copy that current file as a backup (a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy into the same folder and let Windows rename the file), and start a new game.
  I would have liked to verify this first, but, as you likely know, these games are notoriously ginormous.
- Alternatively, I can suggest to just pick up the game where you left. It's an open-world game, dying is nothing more than annoying, so there is plenty of freedom to reacquaint yourself with its mechanics. I just did the same with Shadow of War, after at least six months of not playing, and got into it again very quickly :)

Comment: In addition to death not being a big problem, There are advantages to dying once to any particular captain.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because I did wind up going with the "just play it" option, although I wound up looking up a lot of maneuvers to remember the key combinations to do them. :)

Comment: @SeanDuggan Yeah, you have to through a trial-and-error phase at first, which can be annoying and/or hilarious at times, but most of the combinations will quickly become intuitive again. Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

Shadow of Mordor has multiple save slots.

You can just choose another one in the main menu, and play as much as you want without losing any progress on your main file.

Comment: Right, SoM has two save slots! I think SoW has similar-looking slots, but they're for the DLC storylines.

Comment: IIRC, it actually has over 5. DLCs are also saved on the same slots. There's nothing extra for them